# How to write "htmlstring" in System.Windows.Form.HtmlDocument ,it doesn't have constructor, Is there another way to initialize it?

Tags: c#, dom, html-agility-pack

//This code is not using HTML Agility Pack HtmlDocument .

1) I have html of some elements in string

2) I want to write it in **System.Windows.Form.HtmlDocument** but it not allow because its constructor is not allowed

```
System.Windows.Form.HtmlDocument document=new HtmlDocument()//not allowed
document.write(htmlstring);

foreach (HtmlElement element in document.All)
{                        
    string size = element.GetAttribute("font-size");
    string font = element.GetAttribute("color");
    string fontfamily = element.GetAttribute("font-family");
}
```

Question 1:How to define Constructor in line number 1 in code.

Question 2:I did little research ,I found out that htmlAgilitypack is related to defining constructor but it is so confusing because htmlAgilitypack also contains defination of HtmlDocument. How to use htmlAgilityPack to get attributes ?

Comment: `HtmlDocument document=new HtmlDocument();` should work fine. Second line has to be changed into `document.LoadHtml(htmlstring);`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Yes that is for   
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document  =new  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); 
but i dont know how to find elements in AgilityPack HtmlDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved entirely using  HtmlAgilityPack ,Replaced the code of System.Windows.Form.HtmlDocument with  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document

```
   HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document  =new  HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
                document.LoadHtml(HTML);
                IEnumerable<HtmlNode> links = document.DocumentNode.Descendants("span");
                foreach (var element in links)
                {
                   string style = element.Attributes["style"].Value;
                   string[] styles=style.Split(';');
                   richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + styles[0].Replace("font-family:", "");
                   richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + styles[1].Replace("font-size:", "");
                   richTextBox1.Text += "\n" + styles[2].Replace("color:", "");
                }
```